# django csrf token value="False"

Tags: django, csrf, django-csrf

I have already tried looking at other similar responses but have not found anything that helps. I have two pages that are very similar, but one works while the other does not.

In views.py:

```
if questionType in (1, 2, 6, 7, 8):
    return render_to_response('admin/survey/response_option_add.html',
        {'surveys': surveys,
        'questionType': questionType,
        'survey_group_id': survey_group_id,
        'survey_group': survey_group,
        'responseOptions': responseOptions,
        'max_text': max_text}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    return render_to_response('admin/survey/response_option_add_free_response.html',
        {'surveys': surveys,
        'questionType': questionType,
        'survey_group_id': survey_group_id,
        'survey_group': survey_group,
        'responseOptions': responseOptions}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In response_option_add.html:

```
<form id="frm1" action={% url "survey:process_add_response_options" survey_group_id %} method=post>
{% csrf_token %}
```

And in response_option_add_free_response.html:

```
<form id="frm1" action={% url "survey:process_add_response_options" survey_group_id %} method=post>
{% csrf_token %}
```

When I use the response_option_add.html file, the page works fine; However, when I use the response_option_add_free_response.html file, I get a csrf verification failed error.

Comment: how are you handling the `POST` in the 2 cases ?

Comment: show up the handling of the POST in your template. how do you want the switch from one to another.

Comment: what do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Can you post here the error you get?